# How to make some folders only available to authenticated users or certain roles in ASP MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a MVC web app where it holds certain static assets that should only be available to authenticated users (and in certain role).

I know how to make available some actions in a controller to certain roles, but is there a way or Web.config setting for folders/static content?

Like: anything under this folder can only be accessed by Editor user group?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to restrit access to a specific folder that contains only static contents, you need to add a web.config file at the root of this folder and put a condiguration root like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
           <allow roles="your_role_name_here"/>
           <deny users="*" />              
        </authorization>
     </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Make sure that `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests` attribute is set  to `true` in `<system.webServer>/<modules>` :

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
        <!-- other configurations -->
    </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: It didn't work. Does it have to be like only one level under app root? In my case it's like `static/editors/Web.config`

Comment: I'm reading on the web that `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"` is not so good for performance. What is your experience on that?